# Autofilter then Copy and Paste Range

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, autofilter

I wrote a code below.
Intention is to autofilter column K with criteria, copy data and paste it at the bottom of the sheet on the same page, just below the last row.

I am not getting any error, but code is not working as intended.
It works up to autofilter and copy, but it won't paste the data to the last row.
Can I please get some assistance.

```
Sub Depreciation_to_Zero()
With Sheets("Restaurant")
.AutoFilterMode = False
With .Range("k1", .Range("k" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*HotDog*"
    On Error Resume Next
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row.Select.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

.AutoFilterMode = False
End With
MsgBox ("Complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: How are dealing with the first `.AutoFilterMode = False` when no .AutoFilter is current?

Comment: Try changing `.Row.Select` from `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row.Select.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` to `.Offset(1, 0)`. It makes no sense in this context the way you have it.

Comment: (and stop using `On Error Resume Next` until you get the programming correct)

Comment: Are you trying to copy the data to column A on the worksheet or column K? When you are inside a `With .Range("k1", .Range("k" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` block, `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A")...` refers to column K and rows.count is only the rows in column K; **not** the parent worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DepreciationToZero()

    Const FIND_VAL = "*HotDog*"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, result As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Restaurant")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    result = FIND_VAL & " not found"

    With ws.UsedRange
        ws.Range("K1:K" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FIND_VAL
        If ws.Range("K1:K" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 1 Then
            .Offset(1).Resize(lr - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            .Offset(lr).Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Offset(lr).Cells(1).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            result = "All " & FIND_VAL & " rows copied"
        End If
    End With

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox result
End Sub
```